# Не работает цикл внутри условия.

Tags: c

Здравствуйте!

Не могу понять, по какой причине цикл внутри условия не срабатывает. Будто его нет.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale.h>

int main()
{
    int v,n,s,i;
    s = 0;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    printf("Введите верхний и нижний целочисленные примеры:\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &v, &n);
    if (v < n)
    {
            for (i = n; i <= v; i++) //данный цикл не срабатывает!
            {
                s = s + (i*i); //можно ли написать s+=(i*i)?
                printf("%d",s);
            }
            printf("Сумма квардратов целых чисел равна: %d\n", s);

            s = 0;

            printf("Введите верхний и нижний целочисленные примеры:\n");
            scanf("%d %d", &v, &n);
    }

    printf("Работа завершена!\n");

    system("pause");
}
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предположим, условие `v < n` выполняется. Тогда мы заходим в блок `if` и пытаемся выполнить итерацию цикла. В качестве условия выхода из цикла у нас стоит `i <= v`, а на первой итерации цикла `i = n`. То есть получается, условие цикла на первой итерации - `n <= v`. Но у нас `v < n`, поэтому это условие заведомо ложно, и цикл не будет выполняться.

Comment: @fori1ton, Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Вы же сами пишете условие `(v < n)`, а внутри итерируетесь от `n` до `v`. По всей видимости, `n` и `v` нужно поменять местами.

> можно ли написать s*=(i*i)?

Равноценной заменой `s = s + (i*i)` будет `s += i*i`.

P.S.: Объявляйте переменные ближе к месту их использования и давайте им осмысленные имена.

Comment: @Flammable, к сожалению MVS не даёт объявлять переменные в любых местах, так как она не поддерживает стандарт С99. ПОэтому обхявляю всё вначале.

Answer (score 2):

допустим пользователь ввёл 9 и 10

v=9

n=10

в if (v < n) **-->** true

в строчке for (i = n; i <= v; i++) получаем

i=10

v=9

i <= v **-->** 10<=9 **-->** false

Answer (score 1):

в вашем примере i и n равны и они больше v, а в условие цикла у вас наоборот стоит знак меньше. от того и не работает.